# Проблема с миграциями Yii 2

Tags: framework, php, yii, миграция, mysql

Здравствуйте, не понятная мне проблема с генерацией таблиц через миграции в yii 2, [здесь метод миграции](https://codeo.me/5iC)

А вот ошибка в терминале:

```
php yii migrate

Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf' at line 9
)
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Миграции это просто [Применение миграций в Yii2](http://youtu.be/cugnRoZ1ick)

Comment: Соглашусь, что миграции простые.
И натыкался на ваше видео как раз на ютубе, класные вещи выкладываете. Продолжайте :)

Answer (score 1):

Внешний ключ нужно добавлять через метод `\yii\db\Migration::addForeignKey()`.

Пример:

```
$this->createTable('order', [
    'id' => 'pk',
    'status_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER,
], $tableOptions);
// Foreign Key
$this->addForeignKey(
    'fk_order_status_id', 'order',
    'status_id', 'order_status', 'id', 'SET NULL', 'CASCADE'
);
```

Comment: Странно, тот кусок который вы переделали итак работал, а кусок на 23 строке нет, данный способ используется в миграциях RBAC, ваш пример работает, спасибо.

Comment: @dogmar, многое зависит от движка БД, в sqlite не получится в существующую таблицу докинуть внешний ключ. Хотя синтаксис выглядит вполне себ верным, у меня где-то чуть ли не идентичная миграция есть.